# An error about C++ generic programming

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

template <typename type1>
vector<type1> map(vector<type1> &my_vec, type1 (*my_fun)(type1)){ 
    vector<type1> result_vec;
    for(vector<type1>::iterator iter = my_vec.begin(); iter != my_vec.end() ; iter++){
        result_vec.push_back(my_fun(*iter));
    }
    return result_vec;
}
```

In this program I want to write a map function(similar to the one in python), but there is something wrong, the compiler told me:

```
In function 'std::vector<type1> map(std::vector<type1>&, type1 (*)(type1))':
[Error] need 'typename' before 'std::vector<type1>::iterator' because 'std::vector<type1>' is a dependent scope
[Error] expected ';' before 'iter'
[Error] 'iter' was not declared in this scope
```

What is the problem? (everything works well when I change "type1" into "int")

Comment: If you are going to use a name that already is in the standard library (like `map`) you probably shouldn't be doing `using namespace std`. In fact, `using namespace std` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Are you asking for people to read the compiler error out for you? It is telling you exactly what you need to do to fix the problem, and it gives you a good, searchable, hint as to the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty directly telling you what you need to do. Change:

```
for(vector<type1>::iterator iter = my_vec.begin(); iter != my_vec.end() ; iter++){
```

...to:

```
for(typename vector<type1>::iterator iter = my_vec.begin(); iter != my_vec.end(); iter++){
```

With a current (c++11) compiler, you'd probably be better off rewriting it to avoid (explicit) iterator use entirely:

```
for (auto const & i : my_vec)
    result_vec.push_back(my_fun(i));
```

These only fix the short-term syntactical problem though. There are a couple of larger problems. First is that `map` is already in the standard library (with an entirely different meaning) so it's probably better to avoid using that name.

The still bigger problem is that this whole thing is pretty much just an imitation of (the unary version of) `std::transform`, and you'd generally be better off just using `std::transform` than trying to write your own.

As to the implied question of why it works with `int` instead of `vector<type1>::iterator`: It's fairly simple really: the compiler always "knows" that `int` (as a complete token) is a type. It can't be used for anything else.

In a template, the compiler does *NOT* "know" whether a name like `T::foo` (where `T`is a template parameter) is the name of a type or the name of something like a member variable. To disambiguate that in favor of a type name, you can explicitly specify `typename`. In your case the expression isn't quite as simple as `T::foo`, but it still depends on a template parameter.